# What's the difference in new statement between C++ and JAVA

Tags: java, c++, memory-management, new-operator

In C++, when new is used in a assignment, it's called dynamic memory allocation, which denotes that you have to manually use delete[] statement to give the memory back after. But in Java, we don't have to use delete in the end. Does it means Java automatically give the memory back after use?

Comment: In Java the JVM manages the memory that is allocated, while in C++ you must manage it yourself...

Comment: That's basically called garbage collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses Garbage collector which automatically reclaims memory for reuse.
Read more about it here http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of the big differences between C++ and Java is Java's [Garbage Collection](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx) system which handles memory allocation and deallocation. In C++ if you don't delete objects you can cause memory leaks which leaves memory unusable but Java removes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java and C++ are not as different as it first appears.  You can do either manual or automatic memory management in either language.

In C++ your program is aware of the life cycle of an object and is responsible for releasing memory when it is no longer used.  This doesn't mean that it has to be manual, it just means when the memory has been released, it is immediately available.

In C++ you can have automatic resources management and even garbage collection, though there is no requirement in the language for this.

In Java, it is much more indirect, and almost never need to clean up resources or be involved in releasing them.  The only time you need to do this is when your object is a proxy to a more expensive resource such as a file, a socket, a database connection or off heap memory.

In Java, memory management and garbage collection is required by the Java Language Specification and you can assume this will be available without additional libraries or work on your part to happen.

Answer (score 0):

When new is used in an assignment, it is not the same between C++ and Java. In Java, you are given a reference id, which can be looked up to get the memory address, which you can then use to change data at that memory address. Java has a garbage collector that runs whenever it think is appropriate (low CPU usage, lots of 'garbage' memory), and it runs through the reference table and frees all of the memory and deletes all of the references that are no longer in use by your program.

On the other hand, C++ returns a memory address directly. There is no garbage collector that automatically frees data. delete is required to free the data directly, without any intermediary reference table.